# Mactex installation fails (write protected?)

Tags: installing, mactex

I try to install Mactex on my computer but I get message that it cant be written to the default location. Installing it portable I got problems with the editor and with pythontex (ok, I am a newbie :-) So I would really like to install it with the default settings on my mac (I used to manage to install it before). I dont know why I cant install it now. Anyone an idea?

Thanks
Andreas

[image: Terminal]

Comment: Doesn't MacTeX provide a GUI installer? Where do you get that error message? The GUI installer should ask for your password to get permission for the install.

Comment: I agree with @cfr, that is not the mactex installer. Please explain exactly what you are doing. Mactex is THE easiest installation to install.

Comment: The GUI installation failed 2 times (I checked for the md5 checksum, but it was ok), so I tried this one and the portable option (python didnt work). Now, for whatever reasons it works!!! Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you can reproduce and/or describe your problem with the MacTeX installer package, that might be help us identify and fix any potential problems with it. The installer you're running here is completely unrelated to MacTeX.